# which abbreviation should I use from time_zone_transition table?

Tags: mysql, timezone

I would like to show the appropriate timezone abbreviation for a given date rather than just the Olsen country/city designation (e.g. show 'PST' instead of 'US/Pacific').

It isn't clear how to query the correct abbreviation to use for a given date.  The only difference between similar records in time_zone_name table is the 'transition_type_id column in time_zone_transition.

Here is a sample query.  I figure I need to plug in a real date in order to know what transition_type_id matches the date and then be able to filter based on that id to get the abbreviation.

```
SELECT
  tz.name
  ,tpe.abbreviation
  ,tpe.offset/3600
  ,tpe.* 
FROM mysql.time_zone_transition_type tpe, mysql.time_zone_name tz  
WHERE tz.time_zone_id = tpe.time_zone_id 
  AND tz.name = 'US/Pacific' ;
```

Comment: Why don't you use the tz.time_zone_id They should be standardized in MySQL?  Oh and I suggest using explicit joins instead of implicit SQL '89 syntax.

Comment: Johan, thank you for the reply.   I may be missing something here;  the 'time_zone_id' columns in the various tz tables are just integers and not the common, human-readable abbreviations I'm hoping to display.  For example, 'timze_zone_name' table has 'name'
 and 'time_zone_id' columns with data such as 'Africa/Abidjan, 1'

will definitely take up your suggestion about the join syntax.  Old habits die hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the query you are looking for.  Ultimately you need to join it with your application tables, and select the appropriate time_zone_id as well as replace the hard coded date time in this query.

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.time_zone_transition_type ztt
INNER JOIN mysql.time_zone_transition tzt
ON tzt.Time_zone_id = ztt.Time_zone_id
AND tzt.Transition_type_id = ztt.Transition_type_id
where tzt.Time_Zone_id = 163
and UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-23 16:00') >= Transition_time
order by Transition_time desc
LIMIT 1;
```